# Definite Integral Help?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation

So I'm trying to find the net area and although I got the summation formula correct, the actual answer is not correct

The summation I have is:

$ f(x) = sin 2x  $

on

$[0, \frac {3π}{4}] $

So my change in $x$ would be: $ \frac{3π}{16} $

$$ \frac {3π}{16} \sum_{k=0}^3 f(x_k) $$

The answer I get is -.134

But the answer in the back of the book is 0.753

What am I doing wrong here? (Sorry I don't know the syntax for summations on this website)

EDIT: I figured out how to do it manually but I'm still trying to figure out how the summation above comes out to 0.753? I tried WolfRamAlpha summation calculation and I still get -0.134?

 

Comment: Could you write some of this in MathJax? There are some symbols that aren't showing up in the question.

Comment: [Here's a good website on how MathJax syntax works here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: nothing in your summation depends on k, the index

Comment: @qbert I'm sorry about that, I just fixed it right now!

Comment: What are the bounds of the integral?